# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. Can anyone show me what to do to fix the problem

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, class, oop

I  have this numerical method in python oop, this error appears in the console window. Can anyone show me what to do to fix the problem

self.y[i+1] = self.y[i]+(h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```
 class runge():

    def __init__(self):

       self.x = np.linspace(1, 5, 50)
       self.y = np.zeros(len(self.x))
       self.y[0] = 4
       self.loop()
       self.f()

   def f(self, x, y):

      return (self.x*np.sqrt(self.y))

   def loop(self):
      h = 0.2
      for i in range(len(self.x) - 1):
          k1 = self.f(self.x[i], self.y[i])
          k2 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k1 * (h / 2))
          k3 = self.f(self.x[i] + h / 2, self.y[i] + k2 * (h / 2))
          k4 = self.f(self.x[i] + h, self.y[i] + k3 * h)
         self.y[i+1] = self.y[i]+(h / 6) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4)
    
   def draw(self):
      plt.plot(self.x, self.y)
      plt.show()

 run = runge()
 run.draw()
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: your computation as you implemented it makes no sense. We have no way to know what exactly you want to do... [ask]

Comment: What's the size of rhs of that assignment?  The lhs only has space for 1 number.

Answer (score 0):

The k1, k2, k3 and k4 which you are generating are 1D-arrays with shape=(50,). You are trying to assign this array

```
z = (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) # shape=(50,)
```

to `self.y[i+1]` which is a individual element(scalar) in the array `self.y`

Comment: Thanks, I did the runge kutta method in python and I'm learning oop, but continuous the error yet. import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h = 0.2
x = np.linspace(1, 5, 50)
y = np.zeros(len(x))

for i in range(len(x)-1):
    y[0] = 4
    k1 = x[i]*np.sqrt(y[i])
    k2 = (x[i] + h/2)*np.sqrt(y[i] + k1*h/2)
    k3 = (x[i] + h/2)*np.sqrt(y[i] + k2*h/2)
    k4= (x[i] + h)*np.sqrt(y[i] + k3*h)
    y[i+1] = y[i] + h/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()